# Lines in hyperboloid of revolution of one sheet

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, fix two pts $P,\ Q$ Then consider a set $$ \{ X|
|P-X|-|Q-X|=\pm C\}\ \ast$$ for some $C>0$

Then the set is a hyperbola If we rotate it wrt bisector of segment
$[PQ]$, then we have hyperboloid of revolution of one sheet $S$ By
using parametrization we can show that

(1) it is **ruled** surface

(2) More precisely each line in $S$ has a **unique parallel line**
in $S$ and

(3) it is **surface of revolution of two intersecting lines** wrt
suitable line For instance if we rotate the following lines $$
(1,0,0) +tv,\ (1,0,0)+tv_1 ,\ t\in\mathbb{R},$$ where $$v=(0,\cos\
\theta,\sin\ \theta),\ v_1=(0,-\cos\ \theta,\sin\ \theta),$$ wrt
$z$-axis then we have a hyperboloid of revolution of one sheet

Question : Can we show that $S$ contains a line without
parametrization ? I want to show it by elementary way like $\ast$

We denote by $S_1$ from $\ast\ast$ process Then we have a claim that
$S=S_1$ under the following conditions

(4) Define $S_2=\{ (x,y,z)|z=\pm C_1\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \},\ C_1>0$ Then
$S_2$ has no intersection with $S,\ S_1$

(5) $S,\ S_1$ has same intersection with $xy$-plane

(6) $d(S,S_2)=d(S_1,S_2)=0$

But I can not proceed more

Thank you in anticipation

Comment: I suppose you won't want the argument that the hyperboloid of one sheet is projectively equivalent to the saddle surface $z=xy$, which is quite evidently doubly ruled. (Moreover, using that projective equivalence, you can parametrize [most of] the hyperboloid so that the parameter curves are both sets of rulings.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for Shifrin's comment. I can not understand exactly
"projectively equivalent" but two surfaces have two kinds of lines
respectively

(1) $y^2+z^2-x^2=1$ : Line equation is given by $$p+tv,\
v:=(v_1,v_2,v_3),\ p=(\epsilon,\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2},0),\ \epsilon>0$$
so that $$ (tv_2+\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2})^2+(tv_3)^2-(tv_1+\epsilon)^2=1
$$ for all $t$

So $$ v_1\epsilon =v_2\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2},\ v_2^2+v_3^2-v_1^2=0 $$

Hence $$ v=(\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2},\epsilon, \pm 1)
$$

(2) $y+z^2-x^2=1$ :

$$p+tv,\ v:=(v_1,v_2,v_3),\
p=(\epsilon,\epsilon^2-\delta^2+1,\delta),\ \epsilon >0,\ \delta>0$$

so that $$\epsilon^2 -\delta^2 +1 +tv_2 +(tv_3+\delta)^2-(tv_1+
  \epsilon)^2 =1 $$

Then $$ v=(1,\pm 2(\epsilon-\delta ),\pm 1) $$

**[Add]** I found the thing in the book : Corral's vector calculus - Corral and Petrunin

$x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ so that $$ \frac{1-y}{x-z}\frac{1+y}{x+z}=1$$

Hence if we have planes $1-y=A(x-z),\ 1+y = \frac{1}{A}(x+z)$, then **the intersection line between two planes is in the surface** $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$.